# Angular - ERROR in ./src/app/pages/landing-page/landing-page.component.ts

Tags: javascript, css, angular

I am working on a project using Angular 7. In the project, I have two themes.

1. AdminLTE
2. LandingTheme

See this below:

[image: theme]

landing_page is for LandingPage  while bower_components, build and dist are for AdminLTE

I am using **LandingTheme** as my landing page and **AdminLTE** for the other parts

In my assets folder I put each of the theme's folder there. 
For **AdminLTE**, I put the javascript in angular.json

and the style in styles.scss

```html
@import url(assets/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css);
@import url(assets/bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css);
@import url(assets/bower_components/Ionicons/css/ionicons.min.css);
@import url(assets/bower_components/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap.css);
@import url(assets/dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css);
@import url(assets/dist/css/skins/_all-skins.min.css);
@import url(assets/plugins/iCheck/square/blue.css);
```

For the LandingTheme(landing_page), I tried to put this in the landing_page.component.ts:

```html
@Component({
  selector: 'app-landing-page',
  templateUrl: './landing-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./landing_page/assets/css/animate.css',
              './landing_page/assets/css/owl.carousel.css'
            ]
})
```

But I got this error:

> ERROR in ./src/app/pages/landing-page/landing-page.component.ts
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './landing_page/assets/css/animate.css' in 'C:\xampp\htdocs\customer-portal-app\src\app\pages\landing-page'
>   ERROR in ./src/app/pages/landing-page/landing-page.component.ts
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './landing_page/assets/css/owl.carousel.css' in 'C:\xampp\htdocs\customer-portal-app\src\app\pages\landing-page'

[image: error]

How do I resolve this?

Comment: According to the directory structure that you have shown for landing page, there is a css folder in that. But you are pointing to css inside assets folder. where are these owl.carousel.css and animate.css?

Comment: Create a landing-page.component.css and import owl and carousel CSS there. Reference ur landing-page.component.css in the component.

Comment: please can you give me a sample of that